# image resource taking long to load

Tags: css, wordpress, image, resources, waterfall

My site is taking a long time to load. It is quite resource intensive but upon checking a waterfall of the site load I have two images that take a very long time to load.

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/170919_0K_df1a409e4603bc6459c19cc03cc19aea/2/details/#waterfall_view_step1

I have scaled the images in the WP media image editor so that they are a reasonable size but the waterfall still shows long load times on those images?

[www.linestar.ca](http://linestar.ca)

Any insights are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you resized the image in wp, that doesn't really change the file size. I downloaded your dark banner photo and it was 12.8mb. That's huge and takes a long time to load. Try and get your images around 500kb or less. It should still be pretty clear at 200kb even. It will still have decent quality at those levels. Your image size is also huge, at 1920X3000. Definitely doesn't need to be that large. Check out this link for a rough idea of sizing: [Image sizing for background images](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/best-resolutionimage-size-for-full-size-website-background)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I assumed resizing the image in WP would change the loaded file source so this was a very helpful answer.